# ERROR in Cannot read property 'fileName' of null After updating Angular 7 to Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular9

I'm getting an  ERROR in Cannot read property 'fileName' of null after updating angular 7 to 9. I have updated all of my dependencies to the latest version.

[image]

***package.json***

```
{
    "name": "project name",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.3",
        "@angular/cli": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/common": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/compiler": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/core": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/forms": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/http": "7.2.16",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/router": "9.0.6",
        "@ngui/datetime-picker": "^0.16.2",
        "angular-flash-message": "^3.4.0",
        "angular2-clipboard": "^2.0.14",
        "angular2-color-picker": "^1.3.1",
        "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
        "angular2-flash-messages": "^3.0.1",
        "angular2-modal": "^3.0.3",
        "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^4.6.3",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
        "chart.piecelabel.js": "^0.15.0",
        "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
        "chartjs-plugin-labels": "^1.1.0",
        "core-js": "^3.6.4",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
        "file-saver-typescript": "^1.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
        "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
        "jspdf-autotable": "^3.2.13",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.28",
        "ng-circle-progress": "^1.5.1",
        "ng-click-outside": "^6.0.0",
        "ng-diff-match-patch": "^3.0.1",
        "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
        "ng-pick-datetime-moment": "1.0.8",
        "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
        "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.7",
        "ng2-completer": "^3.0.3",
        "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
        "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.1.2",
        "ng5-breadcrumb": "^0.0.6",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "5.5.0",
        "ngx-bootstrap-modal": "^2.0.1",
        "ngx-chips": "^2.1.0",
        "ngx-clipboard": "^13.0.0",
        "ngx-color-picker": "^9.0.0",
        "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
        "ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
        "ngx-progressbar": "^6.0.2",
        "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.0",
        "pluralize": "^8.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
        "tslib": "^1.11.1",
        "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
        "xlsx": "^0.15.6",
        "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/language-service": "9.0.6",
        "@types/jasmine": "3.5.9",
        "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
        "codelyzer": "~5.2.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.1.1",
        "karma": "^4.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~3.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
        "protractor": "^5.4.3",
        "ts-node": "~8.6.2",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "3.8.3"
    } }
```

When I tried to serve, build the application, it getting the same error. Is there any possibility to track the location of this error?. Is it related to any of the dependencies that I having using currently?
Can any please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: In which file did you get this error?

Comment: I can't track that. Because it only shows the error like ERROR in Cannot read property 'fileName' of null. Please see the screenshot .

Comment: search in your project for fileName and search it.

Comment: Actually I'm using the same keyword in many places. If the problem is related to my code the what is the reason behind the error not showing the error location.

Comment: I'm also getting this error. Happens when using `ng serve`.No stack trace even with --verbose flag. There's over 3000 cases of `.fileName` in node_modules.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: There were multiple versions of @angular/core installed.

---

After performing some debugging, I found a way to generate the stack trace for my situation. Here are the steps I took:

1. Looking at the error message, notice that `ERROR in ${error}` is present. Perform a search in `node_modules` for `ERROR in`, which leads to `node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/utilities/stats.js` in the `statsErrorsToString` function
2. Notice the `json` argument & the `json.errors` array
3. Add a `console.trace` to the `statsErrorsToString` function
4. Walk up the stack trace to `node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack/src/webpack-dev-server/index.js` in the `runWebpackDevServer` function which returns a call to `createWebpack(config)` with a callback
5. Add a `console.debug(stats.compilation.errors)` to the callback from the `Promise` returned by `createWebpack(config)` to see the full stack trace of the `Cannot read property 'fileName' of null` error.

Here is the error output I got (YMMV):

```
[
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileName' of null
      at Object.getImportRewriter (/path/to/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/rendering/utils.js:22:72)
      at DtsRenderer.renderDtsFile (/path/to/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/rendering/dts_renderer.js:76:72)
      at /path/to/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/rendering/dts_renderer.js:68:134
      at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at DtsRenderer.renderProgram (/path/to/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/rendering/dts_renderer.js:68:26)
      at Transformer.transform (/path/to/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/packages/transformer.js:87:52)
      at /path/to/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/main.js:191:42
      at SingleProcessExecutorSync.SingleProcessorExecutorBase.doExecute (/path/to/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/single_process_executor.js:35:17)
      at /path/to/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/single_process_executor.js:56:59
      at SyncLocker.lock (/path/to/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/locking/sync_locker.js:33:24)
      at SingleProcessExecutorSync.execute (/path/to/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/single_process_executor.js:56:27)
      at Object.mainNgcc (/path/to/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/main.js:209:25)
      at Object.process (/path/to/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/index.js:28:23)
      at NgccProcessor.processModule (/path/to/project/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:98:16)
      at /path/to/project/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/compiler_host.js:349:36
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
]
```

---

It looks like `this.bundle.dts.r3SymbolsFile` is `null`. Will update this post as I debug further.

---

It turns out that I had multiple versions of Angular installed. I'm also using [lernajs](https://lerna.js.org/) on this project, so the incorrect version of `node_modules/@angular/core` was being searched for the `r3FileName`.

Comment: Just run into the same issue 'this.bundle.dts.r3SymbolsFile is null'. Did you figure out a solve?

Comment: Yes I did. I stopped using Angular ;-)

Comment: LOL. Well I’m in with it pretty heavy so I’ll need to figure out a solution..

Comment: I think I did solve the issue though. There were multiple versions of Angular installed. Check your package's `*.lock` file & see if you have multiple versions installed.

Comment: Hi all. I got this working by uninstalling all angular version and performing a single clear install. Thanks @brian Takita and others for your research!

Answer (score 1):

After referencing [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32086) (which solved my issue as well),

> Issue is with `ngx-bootstrap/*` version

The error happens, because angular-io-slimscroll has a direct dependency on @angular/core@5.x. I am surprized this even worked before Ivy. Angular libraries should not bring in their own version of Angular (they should have @angular/* packages as peerDependencies instead).

The last commit on `angular-io-slimscroll` was more than 1.5 years ago, so the project is likely not maintained any more. There are also several open issues about compatibility with recent Angular versions: `rd-dev-ukraine/angular-io-slimscroll`, `rd-dev-ukraine/angular-io-slimscroll`, `rd-dev-ukraine/angular-io-slimscroll`

> In my case, After I removed `ng2-chessboard`, `pdfjs` dependencies and updated `@ngrx/store`, `@ngx-formly/bootstrap`, `@ngx-formly/core` to latest. Boom, It got resolved let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Today I upgraded angular 8 to 9 and I got same error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileName' of null`. After reseaches I realized it's all about **packages** and their **dependencesies**. You need to check **previous messages** because answers in there.

In my case I got a lot of warning messages like this.

> Warning: Unable to fully load
>   ...frontend/node_modules/ngx-carousel-3d/node_modules/packages/core/esm5/src/type.js
>   for source-map flattening: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '...frontend/node_modules/ngx-carousel-3d/node_modules/packages/core/esm5/src/type.js.map'

And I checked the `.../node_modules/ngx-carousel-3d/node_modules/` folder but I couldn't found `packages` folder and other folders.

`ngx-carousel-3d` is one of the default node packages and I have never used it in my project. So I removed the package and recompiled it and error gone.

In your case maybe you need to update package (or downgrade) but don't skip the `warning` messages.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game for me, posting in case it will help someone else, but it turned out I had an errant `node_modules` folder farther up the chain (no idea why), which probably gave me two versions of `@angular/core` that confused the compiler. When I deleted that other `node_modules` folder, I no longer received this error. This was with `angular 12.1.x`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you, my problem was that I'm referencing some code by mistake from another project with angular 4, so make sense to get this code in that case. if not maybe is because you are doing an import of angular core or another angular library in a bad way (angular 4 and angular 8 libraries have different ways to import, usually libraries based on new versions of angular include a /ngx in the import)