# ng serve gives the error "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'fileName' of null"

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to build an application in angular and whenever I run `ng serve` I get the error

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'fileName' of null
See "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-r6zMGl\angular-errors.log" for further details.

This is my package.json file contents,

```
{
  "name": "shop-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.10",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.10",
    "@angular/localize": "~11.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.10",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "firebase": "^8.6.1",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.10.2",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.7.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

and the log file contents,

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileName' of null
    at Object.getImportRewriter (<path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\utils.js:23:72)
    at DtsRenderer.renderDtsFile (<path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\dts_renderer.js:77:72)
    at <path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\dts_renderer.js:69:134
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at DtsRenderer.renderProgram (<path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\dts_renderer.js:69:26)
    at Transformer.transform (<path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\packages\transformer.js:93:52)
    at <path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\create_compile_function.js:52:42
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.SingleProcessorExecutorBase.doExecute (<path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:36:17)
    at <path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:57:59
    at SyncLocker.lock (<path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\locking\sync_locker.js:34:24)
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.execute (<path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:57:27)
    at Object.mainNgcc (<path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\main.js:74:25)
    at Object.process (<path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\index.js:29:23)
    at NgccProcessor.processModule (<path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:163:16)
    at <path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\host.js:109:18
    at <path>AngularProjects\shop-app\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\host.js:39:24
```

I have seen this link [ERROR in Cannot read property 'fileName' of null After updating Angular 7 to Angular 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751199/error-in-cannot-read-property-filename-of-null-after-updating-angular-7-to-ang) but it doesn't have a clear answer. I really appreciate it if someone can help me out.

Edit:
I get this error after installing angular-4-data-table library. If I remove it there is no error but I need this library.

Comment: have you tried nom uninstall and then npm install ?

Comment: Are you suggesting I run npm uninstall in the project or uninstall the npm itself?

Comment: I found that the issue occurs after I installed angular-4-data-table. If I remove it `ng serve` works. Now what do I do?