# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'fileName')

Tags: angular

I'm getting an ERROR when running ng serve for angular project.

***Here is my error***

```
C:\Users\lgqli\angular\oshop-new>ng serve
\ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
- @angular/core [es2015/esm2015] (https://github.com/angular/angular.git)
file:///C:/Users/lgqli/angular/oshop-new/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-IUG2QCU2.js:3934
    return new R3SymbolsImportRewriter(r3SymbolsFile.fileName);
                                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'fileName')
    at getImportRewriter (file:///C:/Users/lgqli/angular/oshop-new/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-IUG2QCU2.js:3934:54)
    at DtsRenderer.renderDtsFile (file:///C:/Users/lgqli/angular/oshop-new/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-IUG2QCU2.js:4254:45)
    at file:///C:/Users/lgqli/angular/oshop-new/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-IUG2QCU2.js:4247:73
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at DtsRenderer.renderProgram (file:///C:/Users/lgqli/angular/oshop-new/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-IUG2QCU2.js:4247:16)
    at Transformer.transform (file:///C:/Users/lgqli/angular/oshop-new/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-IUG2QCU2.js:4574:44)
    at file:///C:/Users/lgqli/angular/oshop-new/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-IUG2QCU2.js:4649:34
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.doExecute (file:///C:/Users/lgqli/angular/oshop-new/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-CTSDWZWQ.js:1581:7)
    at file:///C:/Users/lgqli/angular/oshop-new/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-CTSDWZWQ.js:1594:35
    at SyncLocker.lock (file:///C:/Users/lgqli/angular/oshop-new/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-CTSDWZWQ.js:1765:14)
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.execute (file:///C:/Users/lgqli/angular/oshop-new/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-CTSDWZWQ.js:1594:19)
    at mainNgcc (file:///C:/Users/lgqli/angular/oshop-new/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-CTSDWZWQ.js:2103:19)
    at Module.process (file:///C:/Users/lgqli/angular/oshop-new/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/index.js:34:10)
    at NgccProcessor.processModule (C:\Users\lgqli\angular\oshop-new\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:167:27)
    at C:\Users\lgqli\angular\oshop-new\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\host.js:146:18
    at C:\Users\lgqli\angular\oshop-new\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\host.js:76:24
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "oshop",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.0.0",
    "angular-4-data-table": "^0.4.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "firebase": "^9.6.8",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "node.js": "^0.0.1-security",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

When I tried to serve, it getting the same error even when I created a new project and doing the same thing. I have searched through the whole website and can't find a feasible solution for me. Thank you in advanced for anyone who could fix this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR in Cannot read property 'fileName' of null After updating Angular 7 to Angular 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751199/error-in-cannot-read-property-filename-of-null-after-updating-angular-7-to-ang)

Answer (score 0):

Try next steps:

1. remove `node_modules` folder
2. remove `package-lock.json`
3. run `npm cache clean --force`
4. install again all dependencies through `npm i`